# PHP class with property which can be either an int or an array

Tags: php, class-design

I have a class (say Product) with a property (say product_id) and has methods to retrieve information from multiple database tables for given product ID. Now I want the class methods to handle one product ID as well as an array of product IDs (in order to save the number of queries). Also the output will vary depending on the input i.e. for array as input, I'll have as output an array indexed with product ids, whereas for a single ID, I might not need this array.

What is the clean way to design such a class?

Here are a couple of things I've thought of:

1. Have separate methods with indicative names for single and multiple ids (clean but duplication)
2. Have only one method for both types of input, check input type...process...format output as per the input (not really clean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally, always work with an array of values. If there's only one value in the array, so be it, but that doesn't need to change your logic at all.

For input/output, you may want to make your methods accept a single value, which you're going to turn into an array:

```
public function foo($val) {
    $val = (array)$val;

    ...
}
```

And/or, you might create a "singular convenience wrapper" that just makes it clear that it returns or accepts single results:

```
public function foos(array $vals) {
    ...

    return /* array of elements */;
}

public function foo($val) {
    return current($this->foos(array($val)));
}
```

Comment: What do you think is the right approach from the perspective of the client code? Having same function accepting multiple type of arguments (array, int etc) and returning output formatted according to the input OR having separate functions for each input type. If I were to use this code as an API, which one should I use?

Comment: @Vik Either is fine, as long as it's consistent and predictable. If your function accepts one parameter and returns one parameter, and accepts an array and returns an array, that's fine I think. If the output is not predictable, for example because the function has no parameters and may return a single element or an array of elements, you should go for separate methods. There may be more considerations than that though depending on your specific circumstances, that's only a rule of thumb.